# How to get value from state as my vuex getter is returning empty value in observer

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

Getter is returning empty value in observer. But the state is setting properly in the mutation.

Not able to check in Vuex dev tools in console as it says "No Store Detected". I've checked it by logging it in console

Vue File :

---

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('listings', ['listingContracts']),
},

methods: {
    ...mapActions('listings', [
      'productBasedListings',
    ]),
},

onChange(product) {
      this.productBasedListings( product.id );
      console.log('LIST:', this.listingContracts); // Empty in observer
},
```

Store :

---

```
state: {
    contracts: [],
},

getters: {
    listingContracts(state) {
      console.log('GETTER', state.contracts); // Empty in observer
      return state.contracts;
    },
},

mutations: {
    setListing(state, { lists }) {
      state.contracts = lists;
      console.log('AFTER MUTATION:', state.contracts); // Setting the value properly
    },
},

actions: {
    async productBasedListings({ commit }, { id, state }) {
      let listing = [];
      try {
        listing = await publicApi.listings(id);
        console.log('ACTION:', listing);

        commit({
          lists: listing,
          type: 'setListing',
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(`Failed to change  #${id} state to  #${state}:\t`, e);

        throw e;
      }
    },
}
```

Here "Getter" does not have any values but "After Mutation" we have the values.

[image]

Comment: Because initially the store variable is empty.The values are itself set in the mutation.Hence showing up after mutation is called.

Comment: Then how can I get the values from the getter

Comment: Do you mean updated values?

Comment: Yes, the updated value that I've set in mutation => setListing

Answer (score 0):

Because initially the store variable is empty.The values are itself set in the mutation.Hence showing up after mutation is called.

Well now to get data after mutation is fired use async await in your method as below:

```
async onChange(product) {
      await this.productBasedListings( product.id ).then(() => {
      console.log('LIST:', this.listingContracts); 
      })
},
```